# Increase scoreboard when player eats food with certain tag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to increase a scoreboard by 45 when I eat a cooked porkchop with the tag of 403. The only similar thing I could find online relied on checking if you were holding the item, but I also want it to work if there are multiple in the stack. Also the item has a custom name, if that helps.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This was done in 1.19.3, should be the same commands for 1.18 and maybe all the way down to 1.16.

### Setup:

First I set up 2 scoreboard objectives:

```
scoreboard objectives add Eat dummy
```

This will be your special scoreboard that will be increased.

```
scoreboard objectives add Food minecraft.used:minecraft.cooked_porkchop
```

This increased by 1 when you eat a cooked Porkchop.

And one scoreboard player with 1 to Food, this player will be used to check the score. This player is a fake player just holding a score value. I named mine ½ so no actual players are very likely to be called the same:

```
scoreboard players add ½ Food 1
```

Then I used this command to get the Porkchop:

```
/give @p minecraft:cooked_porkchop{403:1}
```

The tag is `403:1`, so the tag name is `403` with a value of `1`.

---

### Commands:

Then the first command will give any player holding a special Porkchop a tag of 403, this command would be in a repeating command block:

```
execute as @a if entity @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:cooked_porkchop",tag:{403:1}}}] run tag @s add 403
```

The next command will check if a tagged player has eaten a Porkchop, then increase score `Eat` of 45.

```
execute as @a[tag=403] if score @s Food = ½ Food run scoreboard players add @s Eat 45
```

This command will only effect players with a tag of 403 so only players holding a spacial Porkchop.

The next command will set Food score to 0 if they have a score more or equal to player ½:

```
execute as @a if score @s Food >= ½ Food run scoreboard players set @s Food 0
```

Then the last command, this command removes the tag of 403 for all players unless they are holding the special Porkchop:

```
execute as @a[tag=403] unless entity @s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:cooked_porkchop",tag:{403:1}}}] run tag @s remove 403
```

All command blocks will be in the same command block chain, this will make sure that even if a player eats their last spacial Porkchop the Eat score will still increase because the remove tag command will be run last after testing for if they have eaten a Porkchop, it's also fast enough so no player can eat a normal Porkchop before the tag is removed.

---

### Offhand:

Then if you'd like the score to be able to increase when the player is holding the item in their offhand, you could simply change the nbt for a specified player from:

```
@s[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:cooked_porkchop",tag:{403:1}}}]
```

to:

```
@s[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:-106b,id:"minecraft:cooked_porkchop",tag:{403:1}}]}]
```

Changing `SelectedItem:{<item>}` to `Inventory[{<item>}]`.

I would recommend using a different tag to check the offhand, then you could change the other command to only look for players with that tag. This will make sure the commands don't spam add/remove the tag:

```
execute as @a[tag=403]
```

to:

```
execute as @a[tag=404]
```

or any tag you'd like.

---

### More:

There is however a small problem: when you're holding a special Porkchop in your offhand and a normal Porkchop in your main hand and eat it, you will eat the porkchop in your main hand thus increasing the score but consuming the normal Porkchop.

I wasn't able to find a way to prevent this, there might be a way by cloning and then checking the number of items, but this would require a lot of commands if you'd like to prevent false positives like when someone would eat a Porkchop at the same time as picking one up.

Otherwise, it works. Eather set up 2 command block chains, one for the main hand and one for the offhand. Or specify that players should only eat with their main hand. Usually, players won't eat with food in both hands, but players might prefer to eat with the offhand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [custom advancement with the `consume_item` trigger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Advancement/JSON_format#minecraft:consume_item) to make such a detection easy and painless.

Create a custom advancement that checks for that specific porkchop to be consumed, run a reward function that can change the score and revoke the advancement again, ready to be used again.

Have a look at this example, assuming you're giving the porkchop like this:

```
/give @p minecraft:cooked_porkchop{403:1}
```

`foo/advancements/ate_pork.json`

```
{
  "criteria": {
    "requirement": {
      "trigger": "minecraft:consume_item",
      "conditions": {
        "item": {
          "items": [
            "minecraft:cooked_porkchop"
          ],
          "nbt": "{403:1}"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "rewards": {
    "function": "foo:ate_porkchop"
  }
}
```

`foo/functions/ate_porkchop.mcfunction`

```
advancement revoke @s only foo:ate_pork
scoreboard players add @s <objective> 45
```

Because we're leaving out the `display` tag in the advancement file, it will be invisible to the player at all times and just works in the background as a trigger for your function.